# Who were the Blue Wizards mentioned in the first Hobbit film?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

Gandalf names the wizards but can't remember their names. Who were they?

Comment: If your next question will be "Why couldn't Gandalf remember the names of the blue wizards when they were clearly given in other writings?" - the answer is because the films did not have the rights to the written works that name the blue wizards.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Apparently Gandalf was afraid of getting sued. He'll face down Balrogs and Maia but he's terrified of Tolkien Jr's team of lawyers.

Comment: @NKCampbell - A better question is why the films were able to even mention the color.